# Scroll bar not working in html/css. Text goes out of the page

Tags: html, css, scroll

This is a sub-page for my HTML and I have no idea why I'm not able to scroll.
If someone could explain why it's not working?
I've tried a couple of things I read from other people that had a similar problem but they could also not fix it.
I've tried adding a div at the bottom, I've been screwing around with overflow and height but I didn't get it to work.

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.factions {
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left: 150px;
    background: transparent;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: campus;
}

#USA-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: campus;
    src: url(../fonts/arial_narrow_7.ttf)
}

.content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: transparent;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Zector;
    src: url(../fonts/Zector.otf);
}

#myBtn5 {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Zector;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: rgb(139, 139, 139);
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0px;
    top: 30px;
}

#myBtn4 {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Zector;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: rgb(139, 139, 139);
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 100px;
    top: 30px;
}

#myBtn3 {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Zector;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: rgb(139, 139, 139);
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 200px;
    top: 30px;
}

#myBtn2 {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Zector;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: rgb(139, 139, 139);
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 300px;
    top: 30px;
}

#myBtn {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Zector;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: rgb(139, 139, 139);
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 400px;
    top: 30px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    color: rgb(30, 86, 207);
}

#myBtn2:hover {
    color: rgb(30, 86, 207);
}

#myBtn3:hover {
    color: rgb(30, 86, 207);
}

#myBtn4:hover {
    color: rgb(30, 86, 207);
}

#myBtn5:hover {
    color: rgb(30, 86, 207);
}


#myImg {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 110px;
    top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        
        <title> WarzoneRP Factions </title>
        
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/WARZONE_LOGO_SERVER.png">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/factions.css">
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="content">
            <Img> <source src="../images/WARZONE_LOGO_SERVER.png"> </Img>
        </div>

        <div> 

            <a id="myBtn" href="https://discord.gg/ySpH6Fd" target="_blank">Discord</a>

            <a id="myBtn2" href="https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/UnitedEmpireNetwork" target="_blank">Support</a>

            <a id="myBtn3" href="fivem://connect/fivem.warzoneroleplay.com" target="_blank">Connect</a>

            <a id="myBtn4" href="Factions.html">Factions</a>

            <a id="myBtn5" href="../index.html">Home</a>

            <a href="https://warzoneroleplay.netlify.app/">
            <img src="../images/WARZONE_LOGO_SERVER.png" alt="Warzone Logo" style="width:150px;height:150px;" id="myImg">
            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="factions">
            <img src="../images/USA.png" style="width:40%;height:40%;" id="myImgUSA">
            <p>
                <h1>United States Armed Forces </h1>
                <p id="USA-text">We are a powerful faction in the region and have proven from time to time<br>
                 that no foreign adversary can match the pure might and fire power that we are<br>
                 capable of bringing to the table. Here in the United States Armed Forces you are<br>
                 expected to fulfill the orders of the Commander in Chief and follow our 3 core values<br>
                 set in place by our founding fathers. Honor, duty, and respect.</p>
            </p>

            <p>
                <h1>Russian Armed Forces</h1>
                <p id="RU-text">The Russian Armed Forces gained a foothold in the region by annexing the provinces of Narva,<br>
                Nazbar and the Rybinsky Republic. Russia has control over these regions and has set up military installations<br>
                there to operate out of. Now, the Russian Government is making plans to push south towards the disputed regions<br>
                and assert control over the Anti-Russian Terrorist groups within those regions.</p>
            </p>
        </div>

    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try overflow-y: auto on the element that goes outside the screen? Any reason why you have everything to fixed? Position absolute probably would make it less problematic

Answer (score 1):

If you remove from .factions
position: fixed;

and changed it to for example
position: relative;

you will get scroll bars, if the viewport is small enough.
You can add content onto the bottom of the page and the scroll bars are working fine also.

You need to correct an image tag also if you have a look